# What is the fastest way to concatenate results of a recursive function into an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

As the title says I'm searching for the most efficient way to create a flat array output from a recursive function.

The following example produces the correct result but it is kind of slow as it has to create a temporary concatenated array of points for each level of recursion.

```js
class QuadTree {

  // ...
  // some other methods
  // ...

  get points() {
    if (this.divided) {
      // concatenate and return points of all subtrees
      return this.subtrees[0].points.concat(
        this.subtrees[1].points,
        this.subtrees[2].points,
        this.subtrees[3].points
      );
    }
    // return _points array of this quadtree
    return this._points;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to speed this up?

I would think that this kind of problem is quite common when working with
nested/treelike datastructures but I have not found a satisfying solution.

Comment: Maybe if you shoulded the code it would not need the temp arrays

Comment: If the code works, and you're willing to get a review of all of it, you can check [the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) of [codereview.se] to see if your question is on topic there.

Comment: switch from recursion to iteration using a stack, concat everything into one array. no more temp arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of is to replace your accessor property with a function (or perhaps add the function alongside it) and pass the target array in so that it can be filled in directly. Something like:

```
class QuadTree {

  // ...
  // some other methods
  // ...

  getDividedPoints(target = []) {
    this.subtrees[0].getDividedPoints(target);
    this.subtrees[1].getDivdedPoints(target);
    this.subtrees[2].getDivdedPoints(target);
    this.subtrees[3].getDivdedPoints(target);
    return target;
  }

  get points() {
    if (this.divided) {
      return this.getDividedPoints([]);
    }
    // return _points array of this quadtree
    return this._points;
  }
}
```

Or if `subtrees` is a normal array, `getDividedPoints` could be:

```
getDividedPoints(target = []) {
  this.subtrees.forEach(subtree => subtree.getDividedPoints(target));
  return target;
}
```

Otherwise, since I assume you want to copy `this.subtrees[0].points` (rather than inserting into it), `concat`'s going to be pretty good.

If the subtrees may or may not be divided, you'll need the `if` in the function. And I just belatedly noticed the name of the class. :-) So I'd probably just make the four calls:

```
getPoints(target) {
  if (this.divided) {
    target = target || [];
    this.subtrees[0].getPoints(target);
    this.subtrees[1].getPoints(target);
    this.subtrees[2].getPoints(target);
    this.subtrees[3].getPoints(target);
    return target;
  }
  if (target) {
    target.push.apply(target, this._points);
    return target;
  }
  return this._points; // <== If you're really okay with giving this
                       // to the caller (you were in your original code)
}

get points() {
  return this.getDividedPoints([]);
}
```

...or any of several other spins on that basic idea.

Comment: That `getDividedPoints` method does not handle the base case where the tree is not divided, it will fail when there is no `subtree` (unless this is multiple dispatch and there are separate implementations for the leaf nodes). Still, it should be called `getPoints`.

Comment: "*if `subtrees` is a normal array*" - it would need benchmarking of course, but I would expect that the loop unrolling is faster here - and it's not like the array size is dynamic in a *quad*tree.

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, that's an assumption in the code (about the trees). The OP will know whether that's something they need to handle and can move the `if`. Yeah, I thought about a `for` loop, seemed overkill but easily done.

Comment: Not sure if its the most efficient way but it in my case of the QuadTree it was 30-35% faster than my original method. Thanks.